# How find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty } \sqrt{n} \cdot \sqrt[n]{\left( \lim\limits_{n \to \infty } a_n\right)-a_n}$?

Tags: limits

Let $a_n= \sqrt{1+ \sqrt{2+\cdots+ \sqrt{n} } }$

How find
$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty }  \sqrt{n} \cdot \sqrt[n]{\left( \lim\limits_{n \to \infty } a_n\right)-a_n}$ ?

Comment: This expression meaningless

Comment: the first to find  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\cdots+\sqrt{n}}}$$

Comment: if $lim a_n=g$ them to find $\lim_{n \to \infty } ( \sqrt{n} \cdot \sqrt[n]{g-a_n}) $

Comment: I thought that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=+\infty$

Comment: @MichaelGaluza why?

Comment: @piteer: look at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedRadicalConstant.html. $\lim_{n\to +\infty} a_{n}$ does not have a nice closed form expression. The answer just depends on the speed of convergenge of your sequence.

Comment: $a_\infty$ is the [nested radical constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedRadicalConstant.html), whose decimal expansion can be found [here](http://oeis.org/A072449).

Comment: The limit is $\sqrt{e}/2$ .. but I need to figure out a way to write a nice proof for it ,..

Comment: @r9m lim $a_n= \sqrt{e}/2$?

Comment: @piteer no no .. $\lim_{n \to \infty } ( \sqrt{n} \cdot \sqrt[n]{( \lim_{n \to \infty } a_n)-a_n}) = \sqrt{e}/2$,

Comment: can you show a prove?

Comment: For $a_n=\sqrt{1\sqrt{2\cdots\sqrt{n}}}$ we have $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[\large^n]{a_\infty-a_n}=\frac12$

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Call the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n = a$.

Let us denote: $$a_{k,n} = \sqrt{k+\sqrt{k+1+\sqrt{\cdots + \sqrt{n}}}}$$

Since, $\displaystyle (a_{k,n+1} - a_{k,n}) = \frac{a_{k+1,n+1} - a_{k+1,n}}{a_{k,n+1}+a_{k,n}}$ we have: $
\displaystyle (a_{n+1} - a_n) = \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}(a_{k,n+1}+a_{k,n})}$

Now, $\displaystyle a_{k,n} = \sqrt{k+a_{k+1,n}}$, where, $1 \le k \le n-1$.

Note that we have $\sqrt{k} \le a_{k,n} \le \sqrt{k} + 1$, so that plugging $a_{k,n} = \sqrt{k}+\mathcal{O}(1)$ in the recursive relation we get

$$\begin{align}a_{k,n} = \sqrt{k}\left(1+\dfrac{a_{k+1,n}}{k}\right)^{1/2} &= \sqrt{k}\left(1+\frac{\sqrt{k+1}+\mathcal{O}(1)}{k}\right)^{1/2}\\ &= \sqrt{k} + \frac{1}{2} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)\end{align}$$

Again, $$\begin{align}a_{k,n} = \sqrt{k}\left(1+\frac{a_{k+1,n}}{k}\right)^{1/2} &= \sqrt{k}\exp \left\{\frac{1}{2}\log \left(1 + \frac{a_{k+1,n}}{k}\right)\right\} \\ &= \sqrt{k}\exp \left\{\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{a_{k+1,n}}{k} - \frac{a_{k+1,n}^2}{2k^2} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{a_{k+1,n}^3}{k^3}\right)\right)\right\} \\ &= \sqrt{k}\exp\left\{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k}} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{k^{3/2}}\right)\right\}\end{align}$$

Hence, $$\begin{align}a_{n+1} - a_{n} &= \frac{(1+\mathcal{o}(1))\sqrt{n+1}}{2^{n}(n!)^{1/2}}\exp\left\{-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{k}} + \mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{1}{k^{3/2}}\right)\right)\right\}\\&= \frac{(1+\mathcal{o}(1))\sqrt{n+1}}{2^{n}(n!)^{1/2}}\exp\left\{-\sqrt{n}  + \mathcal{O}(1)\right\}\end{align}$$

Therefore, $$a - a_N = \sum\limits_{n\ge N} (a_{n+1} - a_n) = e^{\mathcal{O}(1)}\sum\limits_{n \ge N}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{2^n(n!)^{1/2}}e^{-\sqrt{n}}$$

Now, by [Stirling's Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) we have:

$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{2^n(n!)^{1/2}}e^{-\sqrt{n}}\right)^{1/n} \sim \frac{\sqrt{e}}{2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\log n}$$

Hence, $\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{n}\cdot \sqrt[n]{a-a_n} =  \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n} \cdot \sqrt[n]{a_{n+1}-a_n} = \frac{\sqrt{e}}{2}$

Comment: In the line where you get the estimate $\sqrt{k}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{k}} +\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{1}{k}\right)\right)$, don't we need to have $a_{k+1,n}=\sqrt{k}+\mathcal{O}(1)$? Have we shown this? Also in the next line, the error drops from $\mathcal{O}\left(\frac1k\right)$ to $\mathcal{O}\left(\frac1{k^{3/2}}\right)$ that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Where does the "exp" in the third approximation of $a_{k,n}$ come from? I obtained $\text{exp}\{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k}} + O(\frac{1}{k^{3/2}})\}$.

Also, the exponent $1/n$ in $(a-a_N)^{1/n}$ just goes through the sum, this doesn't seem correct to me.

Comment: @Kolja You are right .. I must have missed a term from higher order terms .. added a line for the 'exp' step. Also the reason for checking the asymptotics of $b_n^{1/n} := (a_{n+1} - a_n)^{1/n} \sim \frac{\sqrt{e}}{2\sqrt{n}}$ is that then we know that for large $n$ the ratio $\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$ behaves like $b_n^{1/n}$ which decays faster than any geometric series .. hence the equality of the last limit.